# Flagging records on large mysql file

Tags: mysql, performance, csv

We are currently importing very large CSV files into a mySQL data warehouse. A key part of the processing is to flag whether a record in the CSV file match an existing record in the warehouse. The "match" is done by comparing specific fields in the new data against the previous version of the table. If the record is "new" or if there have been updates, we want to add it to the warehouse.

At the moment the processing plan is as follows :

```
         ~ read CSV file into mySQL table A
         ~ is primary key on A on old-A? If it isnt set record status to "NEW"
         ~ if key is on old-A, issue update statement , JOINING old-A to A
         ~ if A.field1 = old-A.field1 OR A.field2 = A.old-A.field2 OR A.field3 = old-A.field3 THEN flag  record status as "UPDATE"
         ~ process NEW or UPDATEd records according to record status
```

File-size on A and old-A is currently in the order of 50M records. We would expect new records to be 1M, updates to be 5-10M.

Although we are currently using MYSQL for this processing, I am wondering whether it would simply be better to do this using a scripting language? We are finding in particular that the step to flag the updates is very time consuming. Essentially we have an UPDATE statement that is unable to use any indexation.

so
              CREATE TABLE A (key1 bigint,
                              field1 varchar(50),
                              field2 varchar(50),
                              field 3 varchar(50) );
              LOAD DATA ...
              ... add field rec_status to table A
              ... then
              UPDATE A 
              LEFT JOIN old-A ON A.key1 = old-A.key1 
              SET rec_status = 'NEW'
              WHERE old-A.key1 = NULL;
              UPDATE A
              JOIN old-A ON A.key1 = old-A.key1
              SET rec_status = 'UPDATED'
              WHERE A.field1 <> old-A.field1
                 OR A.field2 <> old-A.field2 
                 OR A.field3 <> old-A.field3;
                ...

Comment: Please a (sample of) the time consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider skipping the "flag" step.   Process the CSV file using script or MySql table A using MySQL statement, select a record from old-A table base on whatever criteria, such as field1, or/and field2... of table A, if found, lock and update old-A record, delete processed record from CSV or table A.  If not found, create record in old-A with data.